# Install Ruby for root

Tags: ruby

I installed ruby using rbenv but after several attempts I don't manage to make the root user see the ruby bin.

I installed rbenv under `/var/opt/rbenv`

This is the content of `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh`:

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/var/opt/rbenv
export PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

As user `pi`, `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.2.2p95`
But `sudo ruby -v` or `ruby -v` as root returns `ruby not found`.
How can I make root use my rbenv installation?
Should I fallback or RVM instead of rbenv?

Info: I need to run my ruby scripts as root in order to access the GPIOs.
Note: I need ruby >=2 so `apt-get install ruby-full` is not a solution.

Comment: `not found` sounds like the path is not set correctly. Did you `su` or `su -`? Only the latter starts a new shell and therefore sources the scripts in `/etc/profile.d`. Try `echo $PATH` to check as root whether the setting of your profile.d are imported or not.

Comment: You are right, it works from `sudo -i`. I am trying to have it available in `rc.local` as well (as it is how my script will start) but no luck so far. How can I enrich the path in `rc.local`?

Comment: `sudo` is configured to restrict how `$PATH` is set by default, but you can disable that.  [See here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command).

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling your script from rc.local then call `. /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` before your script in rc.local . You can use `source` instead of `.` . `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` can be used for per user login settings. `printenv` is a good tool to check what is set.